# Do I need to enable canonicalization when using OWASP ESAPI?

Tags: java, security, owasp, esapi

We are adding ESAPI 2.x (owasp java security library) to an application.

The change is easy though quite repetitive. We are adding validations to all input parameters so we make sure all the characters they are composed by are within a whitelist.

This is it:

```
Validator instance = ESAPI.validator();
Assert.assertTrue(instance.isValidInput("test", "xxx@gmail.com", "Email", 100, false));
```

Then Email patterns is set in the validation.properties file like:

```
Validator.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%'-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

Easy!

We are not encoding output given that after the input validation, data becomes trusted.

I can see in ESAPI that it has a flag to canonicalize the input String. I understand that canonicalization is "de-encoding" so any encoded String is transformed in plain text.

The question is. Why do we need to canonicalize?

Can anybody show a sample of an attack that will be prevented by using canonicalization?? (in java)

thank you!

Comment: "We are not encoding output given that after the input validation, data becomes trusted." noooooo!!! You must **always** escape output. The source maybe somewhere other than the input. This is as much about correctness as security

Comment: -1: Data NEVER becomes trusted, if its origin is from a user.  see:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I would say that the question does not deserve a negative! At least it has caused some discussion so looks that it was something is worth asking. BTW data always always comes from a user. It does became trusted when it is propertly validated. This is in fact what OWASP itself tells: use a whitelist.

Comment: You are right. Moreover, Adobe tells this in their security guidelines (XSSAPI library): "Allow all input - Encode all output". The good about this strategy is that it is really easy for the developer to remember and very easy also to check.

Comment: The negative was to flag it for novice developers, and apparently new SO rules prevent me from changing my vote.  

XSS Filtering IS appropriate, but only as another layer of defense.  There's nothing wrong with making an attacker work for his lunch!

Comment: If you edit your post I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one (of several thousand possible examples):

Take this simple XSS input:

```
<script>alert('XSS');</script>
//Now we URI encode it:
%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27XSS%27)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E

//Now we URI encode it again:

%253Cscript%253Ealert(%2527XSS%2527)%253B%253C%252Fscript%253E
```

Canonicalization on the input that's been encoded once will result in the original input, but in ESAPI's case, the third input will throw an `IntrusionException` because there is NEVER a valid use case where user input will be URI-encoded more than once.  In this particular example, canonicalization means "all URI data will be reduced into its actual character representation."  ESAPI actually does more than just URI decoding, btw.  This is important if you wish to perform both security and/or business validation using regular expressions--the primary use of regular expressions in most applications.

At a bare minimum, canonicalization gives you good assurance that sneaking malicious input into the application isn't easy:  The goal is to restrict to known-good values (whitelist) and reject everything else.

In regards to your ill-advised comment here:

```
We are not encoding output given that after the input validation, data becomes trusted.
```

Here's the dirty truth:  Javascript, XML, JSON, and HTML are not "regular languages."  They're nondeterministic.  What this means in practical terms is that it is ***mathematically impossible*** to write a regular expression to reject all attempts to insert HTML or Javascript into your application. Look at that XSS Filter Evasion Cheat sheet I posted above.

Does your application use jquery?  The following input is malcious:

```
$=''|'',_=$+!"",__=_+_,___=__+_,($)[_$=($$=(_$=""+{})[__+__+_])+_$[_]+(""+_$[-__])[_]+(""+!_)[___]+($_=(_$=""+!$)[$])+_$[_]+_$[__]+$$+$_+(""+{})[_]+_$[_]][_$]((_$=""+!_)[_]+_$[__]+_$[__+__]+(_$=""+!$)[_]+_$[$]+"("+_+")")()
```

So you ***must*** encode all data when output to the user, for the proper context, this means that if the piece of data is going to be first input into a javascript function, and then displayed as HTML, you encode for Javascript, and then HTML.  If its output into an HTML data field (such as a default input box) you encode it for an HTML Attribute.

Its actually MORE IMPORTANT to do output encoding than to do input filtering in protecting against XSS.  (If I *HAD* to just choose one...)

The pattern you want to follow in web development is one where any input that is coming from the outside world is treated as malicious at all times.  You encode any time you're handing off to a dynamic interpreter.

Comment: Thank you very very much for you comment! Note that we are not using a black list that is, as you said, absolutely impossible to get, but a very restrictive white list that basically only allows letters (A..Za..z) and numbers (0..9) and a few symbols like _ and -.

Comment: Remember that in Java regex, `[A-Za-z0-9]+` will let unicode characters through.  If you don't believe me, try `String foo = "\uff12";` and see if it slips by.  If you want to block the full range of what Java can handle, you need the regex `"[\\p{Alnum}]{0-some_limit}"`  You should use the `ESAPI.validator` that uses the "SafeString" regex listed in validation.properties by default--though I think the regex IT uses is `"[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+"` which is slightly less efficient.

Comment: Minor adjustment:  `"[\\p{Alnum}]{0-1024}"` and `"[\\p{L}\\p{N}]{0-1024}"`

Comment: Read [this.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#A_Positive_XSS_Prevention_Model)

Comment: Note tha tString foo = "\uff12" is only intepreted by the java compiler. It is not interpreted when it is a parameter.

Comment: Take the Junit test case from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587519/esapi-and-using-replaceall-for-blank-strings) question and modify it to run a regex against all `\uxxxx` Strings.  I think you will find that your statement here needs a revision.

Comment: And as of Java 1.7, you can write your regex like this and it will apply to unicode characters:  `"(?u)[A-Za-z0-9]{0-1024}"` Though I still prefer to use the original syntax in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Canonicalization of data is also about deriving the data to its basic form. So if we take a different scenario where a file path(relative/symlink) and its allied directory permission is involved we need to first canonicalize the path and then validate else it will allow somebody to explore those files without permission by just passing the target acceptable data.